# Writing a list of values to a file

Tags: python, list

If i have lists of values in the following format:

```
[2,6,7,9]
[5,6,3,2]
[2,3,5,9]
[2,4,2,5]
```

How can i write this to a file such that each element is placed on every other line. 
For example:

```
2
6
7
9
5
6
3
2
2
3
.. and so on
```

I am trying to use a for loop for every item in list and use writelines but it is an incorrect way.

Any suggestions?!!

LNG - Python

Comment: Can you show us the `for` loop so we can work on it. An outer `for` for each list and an inner `for` for the items in the list would be reasonable.

Comment: You show four lists, but don't show if they are in a single list of lists or in four different variables. You should be able to simply open a file, and loop using file.write(). You will need to output the newline and convert the numbers to strings.

Comment: `for item in value_lst:`
    `write = str(item)`
    `file.writelines(w,'\n')`

Comment: It seems based on your comments compared to your question that it is not clear how your list structure is, my answer based on your initial question description and data structure is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the `lists` and write the `int` to a file with `string` conversions.

```
f = open('myfile','w')

for i in [2,6,7,9] + [5,6,3,2] + [2,3,5,9] + [2,4,2,5]:
    f.write(str(i) + "\n")

f.close()
```

**EDIT**

The apporach is to first loop through the outher `list`, thereby looping through 
`[2,6,7,9]` first and secondly `[2,6,7,9]`. When these are ireated over, you access the inner list and loop the elments you want to print. Simply access em and print em.

```
f = open('myfile','w')
lists = [[2,6,7,9],[5,6,3,2]]
for i in range(len(lists)):
    tmpList = lists[i]
    for j in range(len(tmpList)):
        f.write(str(tmpList[j]) + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Since i have a huge list i cannot concatenate all of them but i appended all the lists into one list.
So i have something like:
`[ [2,6,7,9],[5,6,3,2]..]`
Now is there any way i can put each element on a new line in the write file??

Comment: thanks!! i will work on this one